# What is the best (free) way to play or convert .amr files on a computer?

Tags: audio, conversion, mp3, media-player, amr

I record numerous **sound files** (record notes) on my sony ericsson cell phone.

I would like to play these files **continuously** one after another on my computer but they are **.amr** audio files which **windows media player** and **winamp** don't seem to play.

- I've found a number of .amr-to-.mp3 converters but **none are free**
- I've found free online converters but they **don't play multiple files**

**Does anyone know of any free .amr-to-.mp3 converters?**

Or does anyone use any **.amr audio players** where I can select e.g. 30 files and have them play one after another?

Answer (score 2):

> The latest version of AMR Player is 1.3 (some small bugs fixed), it is one %100 free software, no adware or no spyware

http://www.amrplayer.com/

Comment: +1 - It also converts AMR files to MP3.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to play/convert more than one file at a time, I am looking for something where I can select e.g. 40 .amr files and have them play one after another

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late already, but anyhow..

VLC media player seems to be able to play amr files. You can make a playlist of the amr files you want to play and off you go.

(VLC media player also has some converting options, although I didn't find the correct combination of settings yet to convert amr to mp3 files)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Personally for me, the easiest way is to the use Use Real Player converter. Once you download real player, it comes as an option when you are installing the program.